# Question involving integration and irrationality

Tags: integration, irrational-numbers

I have a little question on integral and irrationality :

Imagine you have:
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=p$$

Where $p$ is irrational

Can we deduce that there is $b\leq \varepsilon  \leq a$
such that $f(\varepsilon)$ is irrational ?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: What are your assumptions on $a,b$?   For example...$\int_0^{\pi} 1\,dx=\pi$.

Comment: For example $f(x)=1$, $a=0$ and $b=\pi$.

Comment: Even if $a=0, b=1$ there are problems.  Say $f(x)=0 $ for $x>\sqrt 2 -1 $ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise.  then $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\sqrt 2 -1 $.

Comment: On the other hand, it would be easy to deduce the existence of such irrational $f(\epsilon)$ if $f(x)$ were continuous and non-constant, without any reliance on the integral condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Let $a=0, b=\sqrt 2, f(x)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take $b - a$ irrational, $f =$ some constant...